# In what android lifecycle method should sqlite database writes be performed?

Tags: android, sqlite

I was wondering in which Android lifecycle function (e.g. `onPause`, `onDestroy`) should sqlite database calls be initiated within.

Currently I have a model object that is being manipulated by the user within an activity, and is saved to disk when the app shuts down.

I thought about using `onSaveInstanceState`, but I realize that its not called during app shutdown (as it doesn't make sense to save state in this scenario)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle.html#onstop) says:

> You should … use `onStop()` to perform relatively CPU-intensive shutdown operations. For example, if you can't find a more opportune time to save information to a database, you might do so during `onStop()`. […]

Comment: According to this http://eagle.phys.utk.edu/guidry/android/applicationLifecycles.html, `onPause` runs before `onStop` and `onPause` is killable - meaning there is a chance that `onStop` might never even be called! What is your take on this?

Comment: Same page says that "you should **not** use `onPause()` to save application or user data, make network calls, or execute database transactions".